# Increase when smaller than, decrease when lower than

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

Out of curiosity, is there a (language independent*) way to make these two generic statements into one statement?

```
if (a < b) a += x;
else if (a > b) a -= x;
```

May also be used as

```
if (abs(b - a) < x) a = b;
else if (a < b) a += x;
else if (a > b) a -= x;
```

Oh, now that I'm writing this I'm thinking of something like this:

```
if (a != b) a += x * (a < b ? 1 : -1);
```

But that doesn't really benefit the readability. Other ways perhaps?

- = Normal languages, not Brainfuck and the likes or really ancient ones

Comment: "if (a != b) a += x * (a < b ? 1 : -1);" is not language independent because some languages may not have the += or the conditional operator.

Comment: Well, no solution will work in all the thousands of languages. Most regularly used languages have these operators, at least those based on C syntax.

Comment: For those who vote to close, add a comment please. You're being rude

Comment: It's a pointless question. At best you are creating code that is less understandable. What's your incentive?

Comment: Your two implementations do different things. I suspect the first one is the one that is wrong. See my answer for more explanation.

Comment: Like I said, out of curiosity. Is that forbidden? You don't have to respond or bother at all if you don't find that a good reason to discuss the art that programming is/can be.

Comment: For a simpler way to write the second version you can use: `a = (a < b) ? min(b, a + x) : max(b, a - x);` Despite the apparent simplicity, this works for all three cases.

Comment: For myself I don't think that "applying in languages that use c-like syntax"is the same as [language-agnostic].

Comment: Yeah...I didn't add that tag :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a += x * sgn(b-a)
```

Where `sgn` is the sign function:

```
sgn x | x > 0      = 1
      | x < 0      = -1
      | otherwise  = 0
```

Comment: I know languages that don't have "sgn", and Haskell doesn't have assignment at all, let alone "+=" ;-)

Comment: Well, Haskell has `signum` built in. I think I just designed this example to be unworkable in any language ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should really wonder why you want this, the compiler will do fine optimizing and the given statement is very readable.

Comment: I didn't know the compiler will optimize this, good to know. Regarding readability, you are correct too, with the alternatives posted so far. I was just wondering if there is one that is shorter but just as readable.

Answer (score 1):

Language independent is a bit tricky, but if you have cmp or similar, you can use that:

```
a += x * cmp(b, a)
```

cmp(b, a) returns:

- 0 if b==a
- 1 if b > a
- -1 if a < b

Also, there is a bug in your suggested implementation:

```
a = 9;
b = 10;
x = 2;

if (a < b) a += x;
if (a > b) a -= x;

print a;
```

Output: 9 (expected 11)

You need an `else` to fix this. Alternatively, if you want to prevent `a` going past `b`, do this:

```
if (a < b)
{
   a = min(b, a + x);
}
else if (a > b)
{
   a = max(b, a - x);
}
```

If you want to do this in one expression you can:

```
a = (a < b) ? min(b, a + x) : max(b, a - x);
```

I think the first way is clearer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
a += (b - a) / abs(b - a) * x
```

But this is not language independent and does not really help readiness if you ask me....